# Full opacity of fill colour

Tags: r, plotly

I want to create a filled area chart with Plotly in R.

Reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(a = c("r","r","r","r","s","s","s","s"),
                   b = c(2,4,6,4,1,3,5,7),
                   c = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))
data %>% 
  plot_ly(x = ~c, y = ~b, split = ~a, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', fill = 'tozeroy')
```

By default, the fill colours have 50% opacity, but I want them to have 100% opacity. Plotly offers an `opacity` as well as an `alpha` parameter, but none of them affects the opacity of the fill colours.

Do I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could approach the problem like this:

```
data_r <- data[data$a == 'r',]
data_s <- data[data$a == 's',]


plot_ly(x = data_r$c, y = data_r$b, split = data_r$a, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'skyblue') %>%
  add_trace(x = data_s$c, y = data_s$b, split = data_s$a, type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', fill = 'tozeroy', fillcolor = 'coral')
```